# why could not found eyed3 in the conda repo

Tags: python-3.x, conda

When I tried to install eyed3 using conda command like this:

```
 sudo conda install eyeD3
```

show this error:

```
  $ sudo conda install eyeD3                                                                                          ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - eyed3

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

why could not found the eyed3 in the conda repo? what should I do to install eyed3 using conda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is no conda package for macOS in any conda channel](https://anaconda.org/search?q=eyed3), so you will neeed to [follow the docs](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and do

```
pip install eyeD3
```

Comment: my env was conda,I already installed eyeD3 using pip3 command but I still could not use the package in PyCharm. So I have to install the package using conda to make the package could import in my code.@FlyingTeller

Comment: No that is not true. Did you configure a virtual environment for your pycharm project? If so, you will need to make sure to install for that virtual environment.

Comment: I am configure the env with conda, the pip was too slow. so I always using conda, but now I am facing some package did not contains in the conda repo. It is sad.
@FlyingTeller should I using pip as the package manager? seems both are not perfect.

Comment: This also works for Anaconda on Windows.